# SOAPUI PRO - How to dynamically create soap request by adding collection objects based on the Data available in Database

Tags: dynamic, groovy, collections, soapui, ready-api

I have an Order Request which contains Item Collections - shown below

Each Item is saved as a single record in the database table which are bound together by OrderId for a specific Order

Request with two items

```
<orderRequest>         
            <orderTimestamp>                      
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
             <items>
               <item>
                  </itemName>
                  </quantity>
                  </unitPrice>  
               </item>
               <item>
                  </itemName>
                  </quantity>
                  </unitPrice>     
               </item>
            </items>         
      </orderRequest>
```

I am using a DataSource step to pull the data from Database using a Query and have mapped the values from the query results onto the request elements.

However by doing this I am only able to add one item to the order request. Is there a way I can dynamically add objects to the item collection based on the number of rows being returned for a specific orderID?

**Edit**
For Example purpose, I have taken sample values for two order
Step 1: DataSource Step. 
Count in the first column defines the number of item for a given Order ID. Essentially the number of Item Collection to be added

[image]

Step 2: The SOAP Request Step - The elements value are directly mapped to the Datasource Step's column. However as indicated above, we would need to add the collection based on the number of items for a given order
Ex: Order ID 1 has 2 items, Order ID 2 has 4 items. So two requests have to made, one with 2 item and second with 4 items. Currently though I have mapped it directly

```
<orderRequest>         
        <orderTimestamp>${OrderData#orderTimestamp}</orderTimestamp>                     
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <items>
           <item>
              <itemName>${OrderData#itemName}</itemName>
              <quantity>${OrderData#quantity}</quantity>
              <unitPrice>${OrderData#unitPrice}</unitPrice>
           </item>
        </items>         
  </orderRequest>
```

Step 3: DataSource Loop Step - This essentially loops through the above two steps for all data in the Datasource Step. So if I run as is, it will make 6 requests with one item each

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use groovy script to build the dynamic request and set it to the required step as request.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would achieve the same:

Following is the groovy script. This assumes with an arbitrary jdbc test step result set with list of items and build the dynamic xml snippet from jdbc result.

```groovy
/**
* Below is the groovy script which builds data from jdbc result set 
* list of data into xml snippet
* and set xml snippet as test case property
**/
import groovy.xml.*
//For testing using the fixed jdbc result
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Results>
  <ResultSet fetchSize="100">
    <Row rowNumber="1">
      <ITEMNAME>item1</ITEMNAME>
      <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
      <UNITPRICE>12</UNITPRICE>
    </Row>
    <Row rowNumber="2">
      <ITEMNAME>item2</ITEMNAME>
      <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
      <UNITPRICE>120</UNITPRICE>
    </Row>
    <Row rowNumber="3">
      <ITEMNAME>item3</ITEMNAME>
      <QUANTITY>10</QUANTITY>
      <UNITPRICE>112</UNITPRICE>
    </Row>
  </ResultSet>  
</Results>'''
//if you want to pass the dynamic jdbc response instead of above fixed xml, then
//use below statements by uncommenting below one and replace value for JDBC_TEST_STEP_NAME and
//comment above xml statement
/**
def xml = context.expand('${JDBC_TEST_STEP_NAME#Response}')
**/

//parse the jdbc results
def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def writer = new StringWriter()
def userItems = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
//build items element
userItems.items {
  //loop thru each Row of the result set
  results.ResultSet.Row.each { row ->
    //building the item dynamically with data from jdbc result set
    item {
      //add value for elements
      itemName(row.ITEMNAME)
      quantity(row.QUANTITY)
      unitPrice(row.UNITPRICE)
    } 
​  }
}

log.info writer.toString()
//set xml snippet to the test case custom property
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('DYNAMIC_ITEMS', writer.toString())
```

By now, the dynamic built `<items>` will be part of test case level property `DYNAMIC_ITEMS`.

In your request, use property expansion i.e., where you need dynamic value list, just use as below:

```xml
<orderRequest>         
   <orderTimestamp>                      
   <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
   ${#TestCase#DYNAMIC_ITEMS}   
</orderRequest>
```

When you hit the web service request, value will be replaced as you needed.

For quick test, the core part of the script is available [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5143506939019264), so hit the link and see the result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you and sorry I didnt add much detail earlier but I am trying to create multiple requests - have around 100 orders with 1 or up to 6 items in each. Also I am using DataSource Step(JDBC as source) and so the response would be in form of a table rather than an XML Response. Also since the data has to loop for multiple order, when I move from one order to another, I am finding it difficult to skip the item rows in the resultant table of the datasource step which were associated with the previous order

Comment: then show how you get datasource step result look like? happy to help.

Comment: Thanks again. I have added additionally information. Please let me know if you need more information